# Chromium bookmark bar behaviour

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, chromium

I use Chromium on two computers (version 16.0.912.77 on both), one running 11.10 and the other running 10.04.

On the 10.04 computer, when I click a folder on the bookmark menu, then point my mouse at a different folder, the new folder opens.  However, on 11.10, if I click open a folder then mouse to another one, the original folder stays open.  To switch, I need to click somewhere away from the first folder's drop down to close it, then click on the new folder.

So, how do I make my 11.10 computer have the same behaviour that my 10.04 has now?

Comment: Reported as a bug